# How should hierachical tags be handled?

Tags: discussion, tags

Think of a hierachical tag structure/scenario. Currently it's not possible to model an "is a" hierachical relation between tag subclasses and their parents.

A good example are the browsers that are available for Android and the following tags for it:

```
browser
├── chrome-for-android
├── dolphin-browser
├── firefox
├── opera #virtual, doesn't really exist yet
│   ├── opera-mini
│   └── opera-mobile
└── stock-browser
```

Currently I need to look for each of the available tags to get all results, i.e. the generic **browser** doesn't list every *browser*-relevant questions.

How should this be handled:
Should each subtag also be accompanied by its parent tags? (e.g. **browser, opera, opera-mobile** instead of only **opera-mobile**).

EDIT: I'm not suggesting to add an 'opera-browser' tag here, it's just to take the example to the extremes for better illustration only.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so

Comment: thanks! read through it already in parallel. A hierarchy of tags has it's obvious downsides... and obviously is really not needed here. So just asking for  your opinion on tagging.

Comment: `browser` is kind of a sticky tag since the vast majority of Android devices simply name their default browser "Browser". I imagine many uses of this tag refer not to "browsers" as a general concept but rather to the *specific* Browser app (though we also have a `stock-browser` tag). However, I can certainly see plenty of situations where `browser` as a generic tag isn't necessary - what if the question truly is specific to, say, Firefox? Tagging with `browser` seems somewhat misleading.

Comment: additionally: browser and stock-browser will be dependant on the Android version, as JB's stock has changed to Chrome for Android

Comment: Specifically on the the `browser` front, see also http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/899/synonymize-web-browser-and-browsers-with-browser

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue, but possibly other rules apply: I just encountered the [motorola](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola) tag (30 questions). Many of the questions tagged with this additionally have a specific device tag applied (e.g. [motorola-droid](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-droid) or [motorola-milestone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-milestone) -- or even both, making it double-obsolete (see: [Should we merge the motorola-droid and motorola-milestone tags?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1076/should-we-merge-the-motorola-droid-and-motorola-milestone-tags)).

So basically I could understand "motorola" being a fall-back if your Motorla device does not yet have an own tag. But if it has, is it really necessary to triple-tag it? Should we remove the obsolete ones here?

To pick up Flows scheme here:

```
motorola
├── motorola-droid            (CDMA)
|   └── motorola-milestone    (GSM/UMTS variant)
├── motorola-droid-2          (CDMA)
|   └── motorola-milestone-2  (GSM/UMTS variant)
├── motorola-droid-3
...
[ sony ]                      (no such tag -- yet)
├── [ sony-xperia ]           (no such tag -- yet)
|   ├── sony-xperia-arc
|   ├── sony-xperia-neo
...
```

Looking at that: There seems no such "fallback" for Sony devices. But we again have it for [htc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/htc) and [samsung](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung), don't have it for "acer" or "archos"... So how to deal with those hierarchies?

Comment: "motorola" shouldn't be a "fall-back" tag. If there's a device-specific question it should have a tag for that device. "motorola" should be for questions about Motorola devices _in general_.

Comment: OK, but in that case it makes absolutely no sense to tag a question "motorola", "motorola-droid" *and* "motorola-milestone" -- only one of these tags should be used. And if there's a tag for "Motorola devices in general": Do we need the same for Sony devices as well? They also have their particularities (UI, headphone-connector specifics, ...). And how about Acer and others? Or maybe that's a different question I should ask separately?

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about whether or not we "should" have tags for given topics. If a question comes up where it seems appropriate to use a generic `sony` tag then it can be added.

Answer (score 0):

If there are tag slots left, tag it with [browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) *and* [chrome-for-android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-for-android). If there are no slots left, just use [chrome-for-android](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chrome-for-android).

I saw some edits here that removed the "parent tags". E.g. if something was tagged with

[usb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb), [tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering) [usb-tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-tethering), [somethingelse](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/somethingelse)

[usb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb) and [tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering) was removed. IMHO this is counterproductive. As long as the removed tags are not replaced with some better/important tag(s), just leave it as it is.

Comment: Is there a reason to tag something (per your example) with `usb`, `tethering` **and** `usb-tethering`? What benefit does that provide? It seems like using the more specific tag would be preferable since it would logically "group" the question with other ones about USB tethering and *not* with ones about unrelated USB functions (file transfers, charging, etc).

Comment: More specific tags are better. Generally fewer tags are better; if you regularly run up against the five tag limit and would add more tags if you could, perhaps your question is not as focused as it could be. As it is, each tag on a question should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: I agree that more specific tags are better. But it doesn't hurt to have also the parent/general tag, *if it doesn't consume space for another more important tag*. This enables for example to search for all questions regarding browsers and a device, which would not be possible if the browser tag had been removed. I know that this breaks the "stands on its own" rule, but I see no advantage from this rule.