# Should we merge the motorola-droid and motorola-milestone tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request, tag-cleanup

While the tag wiki states the *Motorola Droid* is exclusively offered by Verizon, it is almost identical to the *Motorola Milestone* (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid)). Only difference is that the *Droid* is facilitating CDMA, while the Milestone uses GSM/UMTS.

So currently, we have both the [motorola-droid](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-droid) (x90) and the [motorola-milestone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-milestone) (x30). Should we merge them, and make one of them a synonym to the other?

A similar issue applies to the [motorola-droid-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-droid-2) (x22, CDMA) and [motorola-milestone-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorola-milestone-2) (x2, GSM/UMTS) tags (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_Droid_2) again). Owning a *Milestone 2*, I experienced the similarities in many issues (except for the CDMA versus GSM/UMTS, solutions for the one can easily be applied to the other).

As usual, my suggestion would be to merge and synonymize. I guess, tag wikis could still point out the concerning details.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between GSM and CDMA phones is pretty major.  I'm not sure that synonymizing them makes sense despite their other similarities.

Comment: I have always been referred to the *Droid 2* on most forums (except for specific stuff or ROMs to flash, for good reason as you mentioned). I could check how many of the 30 *Milestone* questions wouldn't fit in the *droid* section. Let me quote Al Everett: *People are using tags to describe their device and not the question.* ([Merge stock, stock-android, vanilla](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/428/))

Comment: besides one being CDMA and the other being GSM, they are basically the same otherwise. I think they should be merged and synonym'd. If not, then there is an argument for having tags for samsung-galaxy-s-vibrant, samsung-galaxy-s-captivate, samsung-galaxy-s-fascinate. While these devices are all Galaxy S devices, they are very different. And there are TONS of Galaxy S III variants. using the gsm or cdma tag along with the device tags would be useful.

Comment: @Izzy IMO that quote supports leaving them separate.  If there's no question-determined reason to use a device tag then it should be left off; if there is, then it should be specific to the device and not a class if devices unless it is *known* to apply to that class.  Ryan, we do have tags for specific SGS variations (or did last time I checked) and they've come in handy.

Comment: @MatthewRead I guess we do have specific SGS tags...

Comment: I see 3 SGS specific tags out of the 20 SGS incarnations around the world. Do you really want to tag for every one of them? IMHO this should be decided on a per device base. And for the Droid/Milestone it's IMHO to merge them. I don't see the a major difference in the GSM and CDMA versions. Maybe you could elaborate the difference a little bit more?

Comment: @Flow If they are warranted, tags aren't created for no reason.  I don't see a compelling reason to merge them, is there one?

Comment: most users that have a Droid are not going to know that it is called a Milestone everywhere else, so for that I can see a reason not to merge them. With that said, they are the same device minus the different types of networks they are used on.

Comment: So let the "droid" be the master, and "milestone" its synonym. Typing "milestone" would reveal it, and I guess at least half of the milestone users know it's called "Droid" in the US. Another reason for the merge: The device is pretty outdated meanwhile, and already had 3 successors. I just replaced my Milestone-2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Same hardware, just the radio module is different. Let's merge the tags.

Comment: May I rise this question again? Merge 'milestone-2' (3 questions only, and not even GSM specific) to 'droid-2' and make the former a synonym? If a question would be GSM specific, we still have the 'gsm' tag to be used in addition (as we have 'cdma', before one needs to check ;)